# Making adjacency list, weird bug?

Tags: c++, linked-list, adjacency-list

Edit: Original problem fixed.

New problem: While loop doesn't break for or statement:

```
while(m->next != NULL || m->val != n)
{ 
    cout<<"Looking for main node. Comparing"<<n<<" to "<<m->val<<endl;
    m = m->next;
}
```

It prints out all the comparisons, including the two that are exactly alike. Any reason why this wouldn't be breaking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m = NULL` is assignment statement, `m == NULL` is the comparison statement to be used in your `if` statement

Note:
Checking `m` for `NULL` should be done before using it for even printing (in `cout`)

If you want to continue the while loop till the last element or till val equals n, then it should be like this

```
while(m != NULL && m->val != n)
{ 
    cout<<"Looking for main node. Comparing"<<n<<" to "<<m->val<<endl;
    m = m->next;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me out on another problem?

Comment: Sure. Update your question or post a new question

Comment: Doesn't || = or and && = and?

Comment: Yes. With a || b, loop continues till a or b is true, exit only when a and b is 0. You need to exit when m->val != n is false. but your m->next != NULL is still true So loop continues